# Why do my while loop fall into infinity?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I want to input a series of numbers and end with "stop", the while loop is to check if x is not equal to the 'stop', it continues add up the input number and output the sum for each loop, however the while loop falls into infinity. For example, my input is:

12

35

56

23

56

455

556

344

22

22

stop

```
    #read the input

    x = input()

    #add up by a loop
    T = 0
    x_int = int(x)
    while x != 'stop':
        for i in range(1, 10):
            T += x_int
            print(i, T)
```

Comment: `input` only reads a single line. And `x` never changes, so of course the loop keeps repeating…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prompt for the next input in the while loop. As stands, you never prompt for additional data and so you will never see the stop. I added a prompt so that it is more clear.

```
#add up by a loop
T = 0
while True:
    x = input("enter data: ")
    if x == 'stop':
        break
    x_int = int(x)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        T += x_int
        print(i, T)
```

Several of us are confused about how you want to enter data. If you don't want any prompts and want to read any number of lines from the user (or perhaps piped from another program) you could read stdin directly.

```
#add up by a loop
import sys
T = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    x = line.strip()
    if x == 'stop':
        break
    x_int = int(x)
    T += x_int
    print(i, T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this program and see if it works. The problem with your code was there is no need of a `for` loop. I didn't understand why it was used there in your program, hope you understood.

```
T = 0
i = 0
while True:
    x = input("enter data: ")
    if x == 'stop':
        break
    else:
       i =i+1
       x_int = int(x)
       T += x_int
       print(i, T)
```

Comment: The for loop is puzzling! I kept it in because I figured that's how OP wanted to sum things. Perhaps he thought that was how to read the extra lines of data. We'll have to wait for his comments to see.

Comment: yaa I got what u said , but it didn't make any sense for me because all it does is add the same int value 9 times  (and yes we will have to wait his comment to see what he really meant ) :)